# Rails 4 scope for SQL statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models, `Player`, `Detail` and `Hero`. A `Player` has many `Details`, a `Detail`belongs to a `Hero`. Now I want to retrieve all Heroes a Player has played. I came up with this so far.

```ruby
Hero.where("id IN (SELECT hero_id FROM details WHERE player_id = 1)").group("id")
```

How would I write a scope for it so I can also pass the Player to the scope? This is what I got so far, but it only groups the `Details`. I would also like to count every `Hero`so at the end I have x times Hero1, x times Hero2 and so on.

```ruby
scope :heroes, ->(player)  { where('player_id = ?', player.id).group("id") }
```

This scope is in the `Detail` model. I don't know if it is the best place, since I want it to return `Heroes` and not `Details`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok finally after quite some time I figured out how to get most played `Heroes` with a scope.

```ruby
scope :mostplayed, ->(player) { select('details.*, count(heros.id) AS hero_count').joins(:hero).where('player_id = ?', player.id).group('hero_id').order('hero_count DESC').limit(3) }
```

Maybe it is not the best solution, but it does exactly what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to use [`has_many :through` or `has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many), so if you use:

```
player.heroes
```

That will bring all the heroes related with that player. If you don't need duplicated heroes, you could use

```
player.heroes.uniq
```

Now, related about sum every hero, maybe you want to sum how many details has each hero? if that's not what you want, please explain it better.

Comment: No, I don't want a relationship between a `Player` and a `Hero` because that would need an additional table. I want to sum up how many times a `Player`has played a `Hero`. I need a scope that does exactly what the `Hero.where`does.

Comment: @daiikota But you already have that aditional table, which is `Detail`, I cannot see what's the problem with just define the relationship between these two models through details

Comment: I wish I knew earlier that you can chain has many relationships with has_many through :/